# Definite Integration: $\;36\pi \int_{0}^{5}t^3\sqrt{t^2+1}dt$

Tags: integration

$\displaystyle 36\pi \int_{0}^{5}t^3\sqrt{t^2+1}dt$

I'm in Single Variable Calculus. This problem is about finding a surface area of parametric equations, and I have substituted values in. But I can't think of what to substitute the variable for.

Comment: I can't go on after substituting $s=t^2+1$

Comment: What are the steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $\;u = t^2 + 1\;\implies du = 2t\,dt\;\iff \;\frac {du}{2} = t\,dt$, and $t^2 = u-1$.

Finally, note that $t^3 = t\cdot t^2$.

$$36\pi \int_{0}^{5}t^3\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt = \frac{36}2 \pi \int_0^5 t^2\sqrt{t^2 + 1}\cdot t\,dt$$

Comment: If you also change the bounds of integration, you won't have to "back-substitute". $u = t^2 + 1\implies$ at $t= 0,\; u= 1,$ and at $t= 5,\; u = 26$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{36\pi }{2}\int_{1}^{26}\left ( u-1 \right ) \sqrt{u}du$$
with
$$u-10=g$$
and
$$\sqrt{u}=f^{'}$$

with [Integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)
should lead to:
$$\frac{36\pi}{2} \left (\left [ \frac{1}{2} \frac{u-1}{\sqrt{u}} \right ]_{1}^{26}-\left [- \frac{1}{4} \sqrt[2]{u^3} \right ]_{1}^{26}  \right )$$

Comment: Integration by parts is fine here if you like, but it is probably more straight-forward to rewrite the integrand as $u^{3/2} - u^{1/2}$ and then integrate.